# MOSFET H-bridge for DC motor

Tags: mosfet, motor, dc, h-bridge, topology

I'm planning to make PCB with two H-bridges for two windshield wiper DC motors @12V that can draw 20-30A at higher loads (normal operating range, without load is 2-3A). I want to drive H-bridge in unipolar mode. I'm planning to use ATmega328p as MCU or some better performance AVR. Is this a good topology for that purpose? This is my first PCB I'm planning to draw so I'm not sure if schematic design is good enough.

[image: H-bridge MOSFET driver]

Comment: Why use a H-bridge - wipe motors need 12 volts to activate them; they don't need a reversing voltage as far as I'm aware. What are D1-D4 there for?

Comment: Do you plan to actively use both MOSFETs in a column?  Or do you plan to use only one, and let the diode in parallel with the other MOSFET turn on passively?
If the former, then the main problem I see is that both MOSFETs will be on simultaneously during a transition due to the slow turn off time of the top MOSFET.
I recommend you use a ready-made H-bridge, so you don't have to solve problems that have already been solved.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm using a H-bridge for driving motors in both directions and for braking. Diodes D1-D4 are Schottky diodes for back EMF protection of MOSFETs from inductive load/motor.

Comment: You can purchase a BTS7960 H bridge for less then the parts for this design will cost you and it comes complete with a heatsink. They come to my door for less then $10.00 shipping included.  It has already taken care of shoot through and other problems you will have with this design. I would also suggest you place your pull down resistors on the other side of R27 and R28. With the appropriate UIS rated MOSFET you can eliminate D1 to D4.

Comment: Take a very close look at the MOSFET symbols in your diagram. What little component do you see?

Comment: @Andyaka To be fair, not all MOSFETs are rated to conduct significant current through their body diode. Though any power MOSFET should be.

Comment: @Gil That's good idea, I've seen some ready to rock ICs like that (BTN8982TA for example) but my focus is on learning about MOSFETs, motor driving, measurements, PCB design... So I want to do it from scratch.

Comment: @Andyaka my goal with external diodes is to get lower power dissipation in MOSFETs by dissipating back EMF through external diodes so I can use this drive with bigger motors also and push MOSFETs to their limits.

Comment: Pushing any electronic device to its limits is great if you want to break things.